# PHP: How do I prevent include/require to add numbers in a loop?

Tags: php, variables, include

Every time I try to assign an include/require to a variable, it adds a number at the end.
I would like to do it without that stupid number.

I tried **file_get_contents** but it does not work the same way.
If it's not possible to do it with require, is there an EASY and SHORT (Single function and single line of code) way to  do it with another function?

Please help me, because it's driving me crazy.

For example:

**FILE 1 (div.php):**

```
<div><?php echo $x; ?></div>
```

**FILE 2:**

```
<?php
$x = "Example 1";
$file = include('div.php');
echo $file;

$x = "Example 2";
$file = include('div.php');
echo $file;
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

Example 1
1
Example 2
1

Comment: NOTE: If all you want to do is `echo` the output of `div.php`, you can just remove `echo $file;` from the end (and skip the `$file =` part on the previous line). If you want to capture the output and do something else with it first, then you do need another answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the default return value of `include` and `require`  is `true`, or `1`.

When you include the file, it automatically outputs your content in the included file. When you `echo $file`, you are echoing the return value of the include, which is `true`.

As a note, if you put `return false;` or `return "<div>$x</div>";` in your included file, that would then become the value of `$file`. Whatever you return from your included file, that is passed to the variable.

For example:

**FILE 1 (monkey_do.php):**

```
<?php 
return "I am a monkey";
```

**FILE 2 (main.php):**

```
<?php 
$monkey_see = include 'monkey_do.php';
echo $monkey_see; // prints "I am a monkey"
```

Comment: I am relatively new at php. Can you please give me an example a monkey could understand?

Comment: I replaced ECHO: <div><?php echo $x; ?></div>
for RETURN: <div><?php return $x; ?></div> and it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: That's still not exactly what you're wanting. Try replacing the whole file with this: `<?php return "<div>$x</div>"; ?>`. That will make sure you are getting your `<div>` tag too. Or, just use `include "div.php";` in place of the two lines `$file = ...; echo $file;` and leave your `div.php` file as it originally was.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
$x = 'Example 1';
ob_start();
include ('div.php');
$file = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $file;
```

*EDIT:* I just saw this example in the manual that defines a function to do this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-131

Answer (score 0):

If you use FILE1 as the template, just include it. Also you can use output buffering as @grossvogel answered.

```
<?php
$x = "Example 1";
include('div.php');

$x = "Example 2";
include('div.php');
?>
```